# add query form along with image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

i am new to Javascript. I want to show a simple form, along with an image on top, and upon submit send off the parameters. The form works fine by itself, but i can't find a way to show a picture on top.. Should be super simple?
Here is my code:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
url = require('url');

var qs = require("querystring");
var StringBuilder = require("stringbuilder");

const port = Number(process.env.PORT || 9000);

function getCalcHtml(req, resp, data) {


    var sb = new StringBuilder({ newline: "\r\n" });
    sb.appendLine("<html>");
    sb.appendLine(" <body>");

   // sb.appendLine(img);
 sb.appendLine("    <img src=\"./myimage.jpeg\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\">"); // NOT WORKING, shows an empty square
    sb.appendLine("     <form method='post'>");
    sb.appendLine("         <table>");
    sb.appendLine("             <tr>");
    sb.appendLine("                 <td>Serial Number: </td>");

    if (data && data.txtFirstNo) {
        sb.appendLine("                 <td><input type='text' id='txtFirstNo' name='txtFirstNo' value='{0}'/></td>", data.txtFirstNo);
    }
    else {
        sb.appendLine("                 <td><input type='text' id='txtFirstNo' name='txtFirstNo' /></td>");
    }

    sb.appendLine("             </tr>");
    sb.appendLine("             <tr>");
    sb.appendLine("                 <td> level: </td>");

    if (data && data.txtSecondNo) {
        sb.appendLine("                 <td><input type='text' id='txtSecondNo' name='txtSecondNo' value='{0}'/></td>", data.txtSecondNo);
    }
    else {
        sb.appendLine("                 <td><input type='text' id='txtSecondNo' name='txtSecondNo' /></td>");
    }

    sb.appendLine("             </tr>");
    sb.appendLine("             <tr>");
    sb.appendLine("                 <td><input type='submit' value='Submit value' /></td>");
    sb.appendLine("             </tr>");


    sb.appendLine("         </table>");
    sb.appendLine("     </form>")
    sb.appendLine(" </body>");
    sb.appendLine("</html>");

    sb.build(function (err, result) {
        resp.write(result);
        resp.end();
    });
}

function getCalcForm(req, resp, data) {
    resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "image/gif" });
    getCalcHtml(req, resp, data);


 // NOT WORKING
  //   var img = fs.readFileSync('./myimage.jpeg');
  //   resp.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif' });
   //  resp.end(img, 'binary');
}

function post(req, resp, data) {
    resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    //getCalcHtml(req, resp, data);
    // do a POST request
// create the JSON object
jsonObject = JSON.stringify({
    "SerialNumber": data.txtFirstNo.toString(),

    "Joints" : 45

});

  // do the POST call
  // works fine
  // etc

}

function getHome(req, resp) {
    resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    resp.write("<html><html><head><title>Home</title></head><body>Test Form Click <a href='/calc'>here</a></body></html>");
    resp.end();
}

function get404(req, resp) {
    resp.writeHead(404, "Resource Not Found", { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
    resp.write("<html><html><head><title>404</title></head><body>404: Resource not found. Go to <a href='/'>Home</a></body></html>");
    resp.end();
}


http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
    switch (req.method) {
        case "GET":
            if (req.url === "/") {
                getHome(req, resp);
            }
            else if (req.url === "/calc") {
                getCalcForm(req, resp);
            }
            else {
                get404(req, resp);
            }
            break;
        case "POST":
            if (req.url === "/calc") {
                var reqBody = '';
                req.on('data', function (data) {
                    reqBody += data;
                    if (reqBody.length > 1e7) { //10MB
                        resp.writeHead(413, 'Request Entity Too Large', { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                        resp.end('<!doctype html><html><head><title>413</title></head><body>413: Request Entity Too Large</body></html>');
                    }
                });
                req.on('end', function () {
                    var formData = qs.parse(reqBody);
                    getCalcForm(req, resp, formData);
                    Post(req,resp,formData);
                });
            }
            else {
                get404(req, resp);
            }
            break;
        default:
            get405(req, resp);
            break;
    }
}).listen(port);
```

Comment: In you inspector in the browser do you see the img line?

Comment: Are you sure that the current directory is the directory you intend for it to be, and that the image file exists in the directory? Adding an `alt` attribute to the `<img>` would let you know if the tags are well formed and answer the question of the file being found.

Comment: now that you say that, i do see a 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404' error in the inspector. My code is now:  sb.appendLine("    <img src=\"./myimage.jpeg\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\"> alt=\"image\""); and it shows 'image' as a text. the JS code is in the same directory as in myimage.jpeg .. i m running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the img tag isn't closing. If you want to use img in line, you should type a slash before closing img tag:  `<img src =... />`

I'm sorry, but I can't test by myself at moment, but another issue could be how this StringBuilder handle slash, verify if you need to escape this character.

Comment: thanks for the answer; unfortunately, closing the image tag (good call) doesnt seem to make a difference.. No need to escape this character, i checked.